# How to install locally an extension in SQLite on a Mac?

Tags: php, macos, sqlite, php-extension

I've no real knowledge about installing an extension. I'm stuck because I cannot use SQRT in SQLite.

I'm using Laravel on a local machine and I'm working on my PHPunit Tests. In one Test I'm using a query with some heavy math functions.

I get the error:

```
Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: SQRT
```

I found out that [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib) has an extension called: **extension-functions.c**

I downloaded it, but I'm not sure if I did everything correctly (obviously not because it does not work):

1. I downloaded it and used this in my terminal

   ```
   gcc -fno-common -dynamiclib extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.dylib
   ```
2. It compiled this data: libsqlitefunctions.dylib
3. With php --ini if found that my php.ini is located in /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
4. Now I looked up for sqlite3 and found this commented ;sqlite3.extension_dir =
5. I changed it to

   ```
   sqlite3.extension_dir =/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/extension/libsqlitefunctions.dylib
   ```
6. and created the extension folder and put the dylib file inside
7. I restarted my apache with sudo apachectl restart
8. And tried my Query and still, it fails. What did I do wrong?

**For future readers**

To use it in Laravel you call it like this:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('SQRT', 'sqrt', 1);
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('ASIN', 'asin', 1);
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('SIN', 'sin', 1);
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('COS', 'cos', 1);
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('POWER', 'pow', 2);
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('pi', 'pi', 0);
```

Comment: Step 5 looks a little suspect. Maybe try stopping after `.../extension` rather than having the `dylib` at the end, since it is supposed to be the *"containing"* directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to use this with PDO. The problem is that loading extensions only works with the SQLite3 api directly, using the [SQLite3::loadExtension](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.loadextension.php) method.

The PDO driver does not allow the loading of extensions (see [this wiki entry regarding LoadableExtensions](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions) under "Security Considerations").

So you could either swith to the SQLite3 api directly or you could use "user defined functions" with PDO. For example if you need the `SQRT` function:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:testdb.sqlite', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
]);

$db->sqliteCreateFunction('SQRT', 'sqrt', 1);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT sqrt(25)");
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo $row[0], PHP_EOL; // output: 5.0
}
```

Most of the math-functions your extension provides map 1:1 to the PHP function names (like `sqrt`), so it should be easy to create the functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are pointing the `sqlite3.extension_dir` property at a *file* instead of a *directory*. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.configuration.php#ini.sqlite3.extension-dir) for `sqlite3`, the `extension_dir` property is:

> [The] Path to the directory where the loadable extensions for SQLite reside.

I think it may work if you change

```
sqlite3.extension_dir = /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/extension/libsqlitefunctions.dylib
```

to

```
sqlite3.extension_dir = /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/extension
```

*However*, I would create a separate directory for the SQLite3 extensions so they are not mixed with the PHP extensions; I say this since it seems like you are currently using the PHP extension directory for the `sqlite3.extension_dir` property. (If you aren't, then please disregard this note.) I assume that SQLite3 just scans the configured directory for loadable modules and loads them using something like `dlopen`. This might conflict if it tries to load a PHP extension. (Who knows, it may gracefully handle this.)

Comment: so I changed it like you said, but still no luck. Though phpinfo() writes:

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 7.1.11
SQLite Library => 3.15.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/sqliteextensions => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/sqliteextensions

Comment: I'd look into what @vstm noted regarding how the SQLite3 extensions are loaded. I was just guessing that it would scan all files in that directory. Turns out you have to explicitly load extensions via `SQLite3::loadExtension()`. It's a two step process: specify the base path for extensions, _then_ load each extension individually. Furthermore, this isn't supported when using the PDO driver.